# machine learning/data mining for pattern data finding

Tags: python, design-patterns, mining

A have some problems in my audio network (I work with IP audio) - from time to time I have a short gaps in my audio stream. I have a logger which record all the streams. I've write small script with python and ffmpeg (and borrowed some JavaScript for visualizing :)) to find the gaps in logger mp3 files. It's better than nothing but I have a lot of false detections - it's quite annoying to to check all the results manually - script finds from 20 to 200 gaps per hour and usually only 1-10 gaps caused by some fault - all others are short term low audio level in songs, speech, etc. I'm looking for high level machine learning/data mining mechanism to check the gaps automatically to leave only what I want. I can provide a lot of "true" gaps (array with data) and "false" gaps to teach the machine and after that want just to feed it with data stamp with gap inside to compare does it look like a "true" gap or not. What can you recommend for the fastest solution? Note that Python is the only thing I can write a little. :/ At this moment the code of gap searching is following. It finds gaps with duration more than gap_min ms and less than gap_max ms in mp3 file or folder with files.

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess, os, sys
import ntpath

tolerance=150#100
gap_min=0.007#0.021
gap_max=0.035#0.03
sample_rate=48000
gap_file_duration=3#duration of the output mp3 files with gaps
ffmpeg_path=r'/Applications/ffmpeg'
temp_folder=r'/Users/user/Downloads/'
result_folder=r'/Users/user/Downloads/tmp/'
target_LUFS=-9#in LUFS

def samples_to_timecode(samples):
    return '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}.{3:02d}'.format(int(samples / (3600*sample_rate)),
                                                    int(samples / (60*sample_rate) % 60),
                                                    int(samples / sample_rate % 60),
                                                    int(samples % sample_rate))

def timecode_to_samples(timecode):
    return sum(f * int(t) for f,t in zip((3600*sample_rate, 60*sample_rate, sample_rate, 1), timecode.split(':')))

def seconds_to_timecode(seconds):
    return '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:03f}'.format(int(seconds / (3600)),
                                                    int(seconds / (60) % 60),
                                                    seconds % 60)#,
                                                    #int(seconds % 1000 % 60))

def analyze_bin_file(source_file):
    print('Analizing start...')
    data = np.memmap(source_file, dtype='h', mode='r')
    zero_indexes=np.where(np.logical_and(data>=-tolerance, data<=tolerance))
    gap_start=None
    gaps_array=[]
    for i in range(len(zero_indexes[0])-1):
        if zero_indexes[0][i+1]-zero_indexes[0][i] == 1:
            if not gap_start: gap_start=i
        else:
            if gap_start:
                if ((zero_indexes[0][i]-zero_indexes[0][gap_start]) >= (gap_min*sample_rate)) and ((zero_indexes[0][i]-zero_indexes[0][gap_start]) <= (gap_max*sample_rate)):
                    gaps_array.append([float(zero_indexes[0][gap_start])/sample_rate,
                          float(zero_indexes[0][i])/sample_rate,
                          samples_to_timecode(zero_indexes[0][gap_start]),
                          round(float(zero_indexes[0][i]-zero_indexes[0][gap_start])/sample_rate,3)])
                    print('Gaps found: %s' % len(gaps_array))
                gap_start=None
    os.remove(source_file)#For some reasons it works badly in Windows. Just comment this line if cause problem. But you should delete temporary bin files manually after that.
    print('Analizing done!')
    return gaps_array

def execute_cmd(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    return out.rstrip(), err.rstrip(), p.returncode

def prepare_bin_file(source_file):
    print('Start preparing binary file...')
    result_file_path=temp_folder+ntpath.basename(source_file)+'.bin'
    result=execute_cmd('{0} -i {1} -ar {4} -af volume={3} -ac 1 -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -y -f data {2}'.format(ffmpeg_path, 
                                                                                        source_file, 
                                                                                        result_file_path,
                                                                                        volume,
                                                                                        sample_rate))
    if result[2] == 0:
        print('Preparing done!')
        return result_file_path
    else:
        print('Error occures while preparing!')

def cut_gaps(mp3_file,gaps_array):
    print('Cutting file {0} start...'.format(mp3_file))
    result_files=[]
    path_list = mp3_file.split(os.sep)
    for gap in range(len(gaps_array)):
        gap_start=seconds_to_timecode(gaps_array[gap][0]-float(gap_file_duration)/2)
        gap_duration=gap_file_duration+gaps_array[gap][3]
        result=execute_cmd('{0} -y -i {1} -ss {2} -t {3} -c:a copy {4}'.format(ffmpeg_path, 
                                                                            mp3_file, 
                                                                            gap_start, 
                                                                            gap_duration, 
                                                                            result_folder+path_list[-2]+os.sep+'mp3'+os.sep+ntpath.basename(mp3_file)+'.{0:03d}'.format(gap)+'.mp3'))
        #print('Save bin data file {0} of {1} {2}'.format(gap+1, len(gaps_array), 'OK' if (result_bin[-1] == 0) else 'ERROR'))
        #print(result_bin)
        result_files.append(ntpath.basename(mp3_file)+'.{0:03d}'.format(gap)+'.mp3')
        print('Cutting file {0} of {1} {2}'.format(gap+1, len(gaps_array), 'OK' if (result[-1] == 0) else 'ERROR'))
    print('Cutting done!')
    return result_files

def make_report(source_file, gaps_array, cut_files):
    path_list = source_file.split(os.sep)
    report=open(result_folder+path_list[-2]+os.sep+ntpath.basename(source_file)+'.html','w')
    report.write('<!doctype html><html lang=""><head></head><html><body><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.1.2/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>')
    report.write('<div>File {0} analizing report<br>'.format(source_file))
    report.write('Searching parameters:<br>Gap minimum {0} second<br>Gap maximum {1} second<br>Tolerance value {2}<br>Analyze volume {3} dB<hr><hr></div>'.format(gap_min, 
                                                                                                                                             gap_max, 
                                                                                                                                             tolerance,
                                                                                                                                             volume))
    if len(gaps_array) > 0:
        for gap_no in range(len(gaps_array)):
            report.write('<div>Gap No {0}<br>Gap start {1}<br>Gap duration {2}ms</div>'.format(gap_no,
                                                                               gaps_array[gap_no][2],
                                                                               gaps_array[gap_no][3]*1000))
            html="""
            <div id='waveform""" + str(gap_no) + """'></div>

<div style='text-align: center'>
  <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='wavesurfer""" + str(gap_no) + """.playPause()'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-play'></i>
    Play
  </button>

  <p class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-1'>
      <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in'></i>
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-10'>
      <input id='slider""" + str(gap_no) + """' type='range' min='1' max='4000' value='1' style='width: 100%' />
    </div>

    <div class='col-xs-1'>
      <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out'></i>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
            """
            report.write(html)
            script="""
            <script>
var wavesurfer""" + str(gap_no) + """ = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: '#waveform""" + str(gap_no) + """',
  waveColor: 'red',
  progressColor: 'purple'
});

wavesurfer""" + str(gap_no) + """.load('./mp3/""" + cut_files[gap_no] + """');

var slider""" + str(gap_no) + """ = document.querySelector('#slider""" + str(gap_no) + """');

slider""" + str(gap_no) + """.oninput = function () {
  var zoomLevel = Number(slider""" + str(gap_no) + """.value);
  wavesurfer""" + str(gap_no) + """.zoom(zoomLevel);
};
</script>
            """
            report.write(script)
    else:
        report.write('<div>No gaps found!</div>')
    report.write('</body></html>')
    report.close()

def normalize_file(source):
    print('Analizing integrated loudness...')
    result = execute_cmd('{0} -nostats -i {1} -filter_complex ebur128 -f null -'.format(ffmpeg_path, 
                                                                                        source))
    if result[-1] == 0:
        summary_index=str(result[1][-255:]).rfind('Summary:')
        summary_list=str(result[1][-255:][summary_index:]).split()
        I_LUFS = float(summary_list[summary_list.index('I:') + 1])
        gainLog = -(I_LUFS - target_LUFS)
        volume = 10 ** (gainLog / 20)
        print('Analizing complete. I= {0} LUFS. Volume change value={1}.'.format(I_LUFS, volume))
    else:
        print('Error!')
    return volume

def run(source):
    if os.path.isfile(source) or os.path.isdir(source):
        path_list = source.split(os.sep)
        if not os.path.isdir(result_folder+path_list[-2]):
            os.makedirs(result_folder+path_list[-2])
        if not os.path.isdir(result_folder+path_list[-2]+os.sep+'mp3'):
            os.makedirs(result_folder+path_list[-2]+os.sep+'mp3')
    else:
        print('Error! File of folder {0} not found!'.format(source))
    if os.path.isfile(source):
        global volume
        volume=normalize_file(source)
        bin_file=prepare_bin_file(source)
        gaps_array=analyze_bin_file(bin_file)
        if len(gaps_array):
            cut_files=cut_gaps(source, gaps_array)
            make_report(source, gaps_array, cut_files)
        else:
            make_report(source, gaps_array, cut_files=[])
    elif os.path.isdir(source):
        for file in os.listdir(source):
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                print(source ,file)
                run(source+os.sep+file)

src=r'/Users/user/Downloads/2016-08-02'
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    run(sys.argv[1])
else:
    run(src)
```

The result is HTML file with waveforms. The result works properly only in Firefox browser.
False gaps:
[Example of the false gap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG6bt.png)
True gaps:
[Example of the true gap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs3B7.png)

UPDATE. Because the algorithm is very sensitive to the volume level, I've added volume normalization before analyzing data. It doesn't apply to the output files - it's just normalize data before it being analyzed.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm sorry - fixed.